# My top navigation isn't working after using my slider

Tags: javascript, html

this is my html page :

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css family=Source+Sans+Pro:700|Dosis:400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../gdigit_icon.png"/>  

<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/respond.min.js'></script>
<script src="scripts/steps.js"></script>

</head>

<body id="dienstenpage" onload="design()">
<div id="wrapper"  >

        <div id="topnav" >
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html" title="Welkom  e">WELKOM</a></li>
                        <li><a href="diensten.html"  title="de diensten  " class="currentLink">DIENSTEN</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html"  title=" contacteren    >CONTACT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="referenties.html" title="Algemene voorwaarden  >REFERENTIES</a></li>
                    </ul>
         </div>



        <!-- "content" -->
        <div id="content" >


                <h2>webdesign stappenplan</h2>



            <ul id = "issues">
                    <li>
                        <h1>Plan</h1>
                        <p>tekst</p>
                        <p>tekst</p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <a class="next" href="#">next</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Design</h1>
                        <p>tekst</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <a class="next" href="#">next</a><a class="previous" href="#">prev</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Build</h1>
                        <p>tekst.</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <a class="next" href="#">next</a><a class="previous" href="#">prev</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Refine</h1>
                        <p>Atekst.</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <a class="next" href="#">next</a><a class="previous" href="#">prev</a>
                    </li>  
                    <li>
                        <h1>Launch</h1>
                        <p>Wtekst</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <a class="previous" href="#">prev</a>  
                    </li>  
                </ul>
```

and this is my external js. file

```
function design() {
    var theImage = $('#issues li');
    var theWidth = theImage.width(); 
    var theHeight = theImage.height(); 
    var count = $('#issues').children().length;


    //wrap into mother div
    $('#issues').wrap('<div id="mother" />');                   
    //assign height width and overflow hidden to mother
    $('#mother').css({
        width: function() {
        return theWidth; 

      }, 
        height: function() {
        return theImage.height();
      }, 


        position: 'relative', 
        overflow: 'hidden' ,  
    });
        //get total of image sizes and set as width for ul 

    var totalWidth = count * theWidth;  
    $('#issues').width(totalWidth);  
    $('#issues li').width(theWidth);  


     $('#issues li').on("swipeleft",function(){
      var ind =  $(this).index()    ;  if (ind +1 < count ) {  
        $(this).parent('ul').animate({marginLeft: (-(ind + 1 ) * theWidth)}, 500);}
    });

      $('#issues li').on("swiperight",function(){
      var ind =  $(this).index()    ; if (ind > 0 ) { 
        $(this).parent('ul').animate({marginLeft: (-(ind -1) * theWidth)}, 500);}
    });


    $('#issues li a').click(function() {

      var ind =  $(this).closest('li').index()   ;  
        if($(this).is(".next")){  
            $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({marginLeft: (-(ind + 1) * theWidth)}, 1000); 
                }
        else if($(this).is(".previous")){   
            $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({marginLeft: (-(ind - 1) * theWidth)}, 1000)  ;
            } 
        else if($(this).is(".startover")){
            $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({marginLeft: (0)  }, 1000)
            }
    });

}
```

what is happening :the slider works fine , but when i want a link of the top navigation, it puts the asked page under the slider in stead of opening it normal. each page of alink i choose from the top navigation goes under the slider ....

when i putted the javascript inside the html , everything worked fine .

and this is my css

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}





/* -------------------------------- */
/* Global                           */
/* -------------------------------- */
body {   
    background-color: #eeeeee; 
     background-position: center center;
     background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family:   Dosis , serif;   


}
#dienstenpage   {    background-image:url('../images/comp03.png'); } 
#indexpage      {    background-image:url('../images/comp05.png'); } 
#dienstenpage   {    background-image:url('../images/comp03.png'); } 
#contactpage    {    background-image:url('../images/comp02.png'); } 
#referentiepage {    background-image:url('../images/comp01.png'); } 

/* --------------------------- */
/* containers                  */
/* --------------------------- */

/*wrapper */
/*--------*/
#wrapper    { width:  96%;  max-width:920px; margin : auto ;padding:2%; height:100%;  }


/*topnav*/
/*------*/
#topnav             { font-size :18px; min-height:10%;}
#topnav ul          { width: 100% ; float : left ; padding: 10px 0px;  }
#topnav ul li       { display:inline-block;}
#topnav ul li a     { float: left; padding: 10px 40px; text-decoration:none;letter-spacing: 1px;}
#topnav a:link      { color:#FFFFFF;}
#topnav a:visited   { color:#FFFFFF;}
#topnav a:hover     { color:#FFFFFF;  background: rgba(204, 204, 204,0.2); }
#topnav a:active    { color:#FFFFFF;  background: rgba(204, 204, 204,0.2); }
#topnav a:focus     { color:#FFFFFF;  background: rgba(204, 204, 204,0.2); }
.currentLink        { color:#FFFFFF;  background: rgba(204, 204, 204,0.2); }

/*gdigit*/
/*-------*/
#gdigit             {   float:left;   width :100% ;  text-align:  left;color: #ffffff;  }
#gdigit h4          {    font-size: 100px ; padding : 0px 40px; }
.style1 {   color: #C5AA6A;}
.style2 {   color: #85D1DD; font-size: 70px;}
.style3 {   color: #000000;}
.style4 { font-family:'Source Sans Pro';text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(71, 112, 119, 0.5);}
.style5 { font-family:'Source Sans Pro';}
/*content*/
/*-------*/
#content            {   float:left;   width :100% ;    padding : 10px 0px  ;margin-top:0px; color: #ffffff;  height: 60vh;   }
#content h1         {   font-size: 30px ; color: #ffffff; padding-top :30px ; padding-bottom :30px ;text-align:  left; }
#content h2         {   font-size: 22px ; color: #ffffff; padding :20px 40px 10px 40px;  text-align:  left;text-transform:uppercase; letter-spacing:2px; }
#content h3         {   font-size: 16px ; color: #ffffff; padding-top :20px ; padding-bottom :20px  ;text-align:  left; }
#content h4         {   font-size: 100px ; font-weight:bold; text-align: center;  }
#content p          {   font-size: 22px; color: #ffffff;line-height:170%;text-align:justify;padding :0px 40px 0px 40px;}
#container01        {   float:right;   width :70% ;text-align:center ;margin-top: 100px; }
#container01 p      {   font-size: 22px; color: #ffffff;line-height:170%;padding :0px 40px 0px 40px;text-align:  center ;}
.tekstkolommen      {   overflow: hidden;  padding:0px  ; width:100%; }
.kolomlinks         {   float:left;  width:35%;  }
.kolomrechts        {   float:right; width:63%; }
.kolomlinks div, .kolomrechts div   { margin:0px;  padding:8px 0px 0px 40px;    font-size:18px; }
.coli               {   font-size: 22px; color:#FFFFFF;text-align :  left;line-height:210%;padding-left:40px;}
.staplink           {   color:#FFFFFF;  background: rgba(204, 204, 204,0.4);text-transform:uppercase;text-decoration:none;letter-spacing:3px;}
a:link              {   color:#FFFFFF}
a:visited           {   color:#FFFFFF}
a:hover             {   color:#FFFFFF}
a:active            {   color:#FFFFFF}
a:focus             {   color:#FFFFFF;  background: rgba(204, 204, 204,0.2); }
#content ul li      {   font-size: 20px;line-height:170%; }
#content ul         {   padding-top:10px;}
#issues             {    }  
#issues li          {list-style: none;  float: left; position:relative;     color: #FFFFFF; }  
#issues li a        {text-indent:-9999px; }
#issues li a.next     { position:absolute; right:0px; top :100px;  width: 0;  
                        height: 0; 
                        border-top: 40px solid transparent;
                        border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
                        border-left: 25px solid #85D1DD; }
#issues li a.previous { position:absolute; left: 0px; top :100px;  
                        height: 0; 
                        border-top: 40px solid transparent;
                        border-right: 25px solid #85D1DD;
                        border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;     }
#issues li a.startover{position:absolute; right:20px;  top :0px;}
#issues li h1       {   color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 22px;margin-left: 40px;margin-right: 40px;color: #ffffff;  text-transform:uppercase;      }
#issues li p        {   font-size: 20px;        font-weight: normal;color: #ffffff; line-height:170%;   text-align:justify;    }





/*forms */
/*------*/
form                { color:#FFFFFF;width:100%;  }
submit,input,textarea{background: rgba(204, 204, 204,0.6);color :#FFFFFF; padding: 3px;width:70%; border:1px  solid #FFFFFF;font-size:20px;font-family:Dosis,serif; }
.style6             { margin-top: 30px; margin-left:25%; width:72%; }
#contact-form ol    { list-style-type:none;}
#contact-form ol li { font-size:20px;}
#contact-form p     { float:left; font-size:20px; width: 100%;}
#contact-form label { float:left; width:25%;}
#contact-form li    { margin-top:5px; }
#fout                

/*footer*/
/*------*/
#footer             {clear:both;width:100% ; color : #FFFFFF; font-size:11px;  }
#footer h4          {font-size: 100px ; font-weight:bold; text-align: left; }



/* Media Queries */
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 800px)  
{
#gdigit h4          {   font-size: 70px ; padding : 0px 40px; }
.kolomlinks         {   width:42%; }
.kolomrechts        {   width:58%; }
.coli               {   line-height:120%;}
label               {   width:100% ; }
submit,input,textarea,input{ width:95%; float:left;background: rgba(204, 204, 204,0.3); }
.style6             {   margin-top: 20px; margin-left:0; width:50%; }
#issues li a.next   {   border-top: 30px solid transparent;
                        border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
                        border-left: 20px solid #85D1DD; }
#issues li a.previous { border-top: 30px solid transparent;
                        border-right: 20px solid #85D1DD;
                        border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;     }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px)  
{
#dienstenpage       {   background-image:url(../images/compmob3.png); } 
#indexpage          {   background-image:url(../images/compmob5.png); } 
#dienstenpage       {   background-image:url(../images/compmob3.png); } 
#contactpage        {   background-image:url(../images/compmob2.png); } 
#referentiepage     {   background-image:url(../images/compmob1.png); } 
#topnav             {   padding-top:  5px;padding-bottom : 0px;}
#gdigit h4          {   font-size: 70px ; padding : 0px 40px; }
#content            {   margin-top:10px;padding-top : 0;margin-bottom :30px;}
#content p          {   font-size: 18px; color: #ffffff;line-height:110%;text-align:justify;}
#container01        {   float:left;   width :100% ;text-align:  center ;margin-top: 0px;}
#container01 p      {   font-size: 18px; color: #ffffff;line-height:100%;text-align: justify ;padding-bottom:10px;}
#content h4         {   font-size: 70px ; font-weight:bold; text-align: center;  }
.style2             {   color: #85D1DD; font-size: 45px;}
.style3             {   color: #000000;}
.style4             {   background: rgba(204, 204, 204,0.2);    }
.style6             {   margin-top: 10px; margin-left:0; width:100%; }
.kolomlinks         {   float:left;  width:100%; }
.kolomrechts        {   float:left; width:100%; }
.coli               {   line-height:120%;}
label               {   width:100% ; }
submit,input,textarea,input{ width:95%; float:left;background: rgba(204, 204, 204,0.3); }
.style5             {   margin-top: 10px;  width:100%; margin-left:0;background: rgba(204, 204, 204,0.3);}
#footer             {   clear:both;  width:100% ;   color: #FFFFFF;   position : relative; min-height : 150px; }
#footer h4          {   font-size: 50px ; font-weight:bold; text-align: center;height :60px;}
#issues li a.next   {   border-top: 30px solid transparent;
                        border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
                        border-left: 20px solid #85D1DD; }
#issues li a.previous { border-top: 30px solid transparent;
                        border-right: 20px solid #85D1DD;
                        border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;     }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide your CSS file?

Comment: and the problem starts only after clicking orswiping once on the slider. Ik just go on the page and not use the slider , the top navigation works correctly

Comment: is this something with jquery ?

Comment: I will try to help you soon please wait

Comment: is there anyone who can help me please ???

Answer (score 0):

when you add bootstrap with jQuery Mobile it will create some conflict, It may disturb your css or some jquery event, so you are recommended to use just custom feature when you use jQuery Mobile in your template,

http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

you can create your custom jQuery mobile file, and check only those feature you want in your mobile.

Many Thanks